# Should I store refund records in positive or negative amount?

Tags: finance

I am asking for best practice from veteran Financial programmers.

eg PSUDO code:

```
class Transaction(Model):
    order = ForeignKey()
    amount = DecimalField()
    type = 'refund' or 'purchase'
```

If storing refunds in negative amount, then I can simply run `sum()` of all transactions to get the balance, math operations become a bit native.

If storing refunds in positive amount, then it's more human friendly on formula like `purchase - refund = balance`, also I don't need to invert to display a positive amount of refund in template.

Which one should I pick to have most benefits and less gotchas?

Comment: A refund is a positive amount.

Comment: How do you plan on using the refunds and purchases?

Comment: @DaveNewton - Why are refunds necessarily positive amounts?  From the customer's perspective they may be positive.  But from the business's perspective they are surely negative.

Comment: @HappyNomad A payment is a positive amount--you can't pay someone negative dollars. A business writes a check to someone for $100. It subtracts that positive amount from its holdings.

Comment: @DaveNewton - I think you're saying a value that's explicitly labeled as "payment" or "refund" is positive.  That makes sense, but how about a more general "transaction amount" that represents both payment and refund amounts?  When is it positive vs. negative?

Comment: @HappyNomad No idea (or why this conversation is happening). In general I'd base business logic (adding or subtracting) based on a type, but ultimately it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @DaveNewton - There's only one type mentioned in the question, i.e. "Transaction".  So the word "refund" refers to a transaction representing a refund.  You said that "a refund is a positive amount", but you didn't say why.  It seems you're assuming there are two unrelated types, i.e. Payment and Refund.

Comment: @HappyNomad ... OP asks specifically about refunds, I provided my opinion.

Comment: @HappyNomad ... Cool, enjoy. There's one `Transaction` *class*. There are two transaction types, indicated by the OP's `type` property. OP asked about refunds. I said refunds are positive. There's no reason a payment cannot also be positive, with the business logic tied to the transaction type. Like I said before. Carry on--no clue why you care.

Comment: @DaveNewton - After posting my previous comment I reread the question and realized that, as you said, "There's no reason a payment cannot also be positive".  I implemented everything as positive in my system a few months ago, so an earlier version of myself would have agreed with you.  But taking polymorphism into consideration now, I'm thinking it's bad object-oriented design.  It gives Transaction.Amount two meanings depending on Transaction.Type.

Comment: @HappyNomad The meaning of the amount is always the same; it's an amount. The "error" in the OP's OOD is that two types are represented in the same class (I think that's what you're saying) and the difference in "meaning" is handled elsewhere. It'd be handled elsewhere if it was two distinct types, too, in a TransactionProcessor of some sort. Meh.

Comment: @DaveNewton - The meaning of Transaction.Amount is the same for payments and refunds only if, as OP worded it, "I can simply run sum() of all transactions".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to have an `amount` field that holds the value as positive and another field like `signedAmount` that holds the signed version of it. So, when you want to display or log it you use `amount`, when you want to include it in a calculation you use `signedAmount`.